# SUMIFS with Complex Date Range Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Basically I have 2 sheets, ' Time Off Requests' and ' Employee Time Off Data'.

I am trying to write a formula that adds the amount of Days the employees have requested off within the ' Time Off Requests' tab using a specified date range on ' Employee Time Off Data'.

However, if the "Start Date" or "End Date" on the ' Time Off Requests' tab falls outside of the specified date range on the ' Employee Time Off Data' tab, it is not counted.

My way around this was to only use the "Start Date" to apply the date range to, and SUMIF ' Time Off Requests'!$G:$G (a column of manually entered numbers of days off [AKA: "Days Requested"]).

Still, it would **EITHER**:
Not count the "# of Requested Days" because the "Start Date" falls short the date range (but the "End Date" is within the date range - meaning there is a portion of the listed "Days Requested" that **should** be counted)

• OR •
It would inaccurately count the "# of Requested Days" because the "Start Date" falls within the date range (but the "End Date" is after the date range - meaning there is a portion of the listed "Days Requested" that **was** counted, but **not used** within that date range).

**This is what I cannot figure out how to work around.**

Here are screenshots of the two tabs as well as the code I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

' Time Off Requests': https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrwkN.png

' Employee Time Off Data': https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTpkh.png

My Current Formula:

```
=IF($B14 <> "",
IF(
SUMIFS(' Time Off Requests'!$G:$G, ' Time Off Requests'!$D:$D, $B14, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E, ">=" & $I$2, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E, "<=" & $J$2) =
SUMIFS(' Time Off Requests'!$G:$G, ' Time Off Requests'!$D:$D, $B14, ' Time Off Requests'!$F:$F, ">=" & $I$2, ' Time Off Requests'!$F:$F, "<=" & $J$2),
SUMIFS(' Time Off Requests'!$G:$G, ' Time Off Requests'!$D:$D, $B14, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E, ">=" & $I$2, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E, "<=" & $J$2),
IF(
SUMIFS(' Time Off Requests'!$G:$G, ' Time Off Requests'!$D:$D, $B14, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E, ">=" & $I$2, ' Time Off Requests'!$F:$F, "<=" & $J$2) = 0,
DAYS($I$2, ' Time Off Requests'!$E:$E),
""
)))
```

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @AndrewIgel. Did you solve your problem?